# BeatsMusic API: How do I get albums an artist appears on?

Tags: beatsmusic

The method call for /artists/[artist id]/albums returns only Albums, EPs, Singles and Compilations attributed to that artist.

I want to get the albums the artist appears on but are not attributed to that artist, e.g. various artists compilations where the artist has one track, or albums where the artist is a guest artist.

How do I get these "appears on"-albums for an artist? Preferrably without making more than one HTTP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a direct way to set list every album the artist appears on in our public API. If you use artist/tracks, you will receive a list of tracks the artist appears on including soundtracks, compilations, etc., however, the full album list doesn't include every appearance.

Comment: OK I see. It would be a nice feature to get appearances directly. If I want all appearances listed now I would have to get the tracks, filter only those tracks not in an album credited to the artist, and then take a unique list of albums those tracks belong to. Looks like the tracks result contains album display name and IDs, so I should get what I need from this approach.